# How to debug my C gstreamer code?

Tags: c, debugging, gstreamer

I succesfully program and execute the `helloworld.c` in the [Application Development Manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf) page 43. It works very well.

The compilation was done using this command line

```
gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld $(pkg-conﬁg --cﬂags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
```

I'm using the default gstreamer installed on my `ubuntu 12.0.4`.

I'm concerned about debugging my program and I know that this can be achieved using command line option `GST_DEBUG`. Here is an example where the debug report of the `qtdemux`is generated in a csv file.

```
GST_DEBUG=qtdemux:5 gst-launch filesrc location=/home/pub_Irma.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink 2> > (tee /media/thesis/log_pub.csv)
```

But since I'm not using `gst-launch`, I'm wonder how to do the same programmatically ? what is missing in manual code to produce a debug report ? Or is there a special parameter to set when compiling or/and executing the program ?

I've tried compiling this way

```
gcc $2 -o $3 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10 --enable-gst-debug`
```

but without success

thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found that this can be done in execution time by running the program this way

```
GST_DEBUG=oggdemux:5 ./helloworld file.ogg
```

the above example debug the ogg demuxer

Answer (score 0):

GST_DEBUG is a environment variable that can be used with any gstreamer app, as long as the logging subsystem is not disabled. Please note, that the output is not in cvs format. I recommend to use gst-debug-viewer to digg thought the output (get it from freedesktop git).